# Making Last Visited items list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm making a webpage in mvc 3. 
I want to make a list with last visited items withe no need login.
Something like www.booking.com -> "My viewed hotels",
If any one can give your opinion, I appreciate. thanks a lot.

Comment: haven't worked in C sharp , but I presume you need to use sessions. Or you can record details in db and then retrieve them. But it is usually done via http sessions.

Answer (score 1):

From what comes to my mind, you have two options: use a [cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx) or the [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms178581.aspx) object.

For more complete info: [ASP.NET State Management Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx)

Take a look at this too:

[How do I track users of my app without forcing them to register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4084042/114029)